# hide subtotal from cart magento

Tags: hide, magento-1.7, cart, subtotal

How to hide Unit Price and Subtotal from Magento cart ver. 1.7.0.2
Previously it worked at the following lines on

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
online number  104 , 106 ,196 , 198

and few changes in 
/public_html/bestmfg.fillcraft.org/app/design/frontend/default/buyshop/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Answer (score -1):

You can change this in the administration area:

> System -> Configuration -> Tax (Under "SALES" tab on the left).

Comment: this answer is not the solution. I have solved the issue by amending the code in magento. The solution is same as mentioned in my question, but modifications should be made both in base and custom theme.

Comment: If you are using a theme created by magical unicorns that did not inherit from the default Magento theme (the way these subtotals, ... are printed) then yes indeed this answer might not be the solution but your question would be too localized too. PS: Glad you found it.

Comment: As far as I can tell this only offers to display prices including tax, excluding tax, or both. It does not offer to show neither.